# Toggle all data series upon clicking a legend in Apex charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, apexcharts

In the below chart, assume there is the fourth legend say, 'All' and when I click on it, all the data should disappear. When I click it back again, all data must re-appear. Is there a way to do it in apex charts?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a new button within the div where the chart is added and have an onclick action for it which will call the function toggle series

```
<div className={"chart-item " + className} key={index}>
  <Chart series={option.series} options={option} height={600} />
  <div className="all-lines">
    <input
      className="button-css"
      type="button"
      value={toggleText[index]}
      onClick={(e) => {
        toggleSeries(option?.chart?.id, option?.series, e);
      }}
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

The toggle series function will hide or display all legends depending upon the current state of the chart.

```
function toggleSeries(
      id: string | undefined,
      series: ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries | undefined,
      e: any
    ) {
      const functionName =
        e.target.value === hideText ? "hideSeries" : "showSeries";
      e.target.value = e.target.value === hideText ? showText : hideText;
      const chartSeries: ApexAxisChartSeries | undefined = series
        ? (series as ApexAxisChartSeries)
        : undefined;
      const chartId = id ? id : "";

      chartSeries?.forEach((ser) => {
        ApexCharts.exec(chartId, functionName, ser.name);
      });
    }

    return lineChartItems;
  }
```